# using chosen.js on my react application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, jquery-chosen

I am trying to use chosen.js in my react application.
However, although I have read the documentation about refs and stuffs here( https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html ), I don't really get anything it's saying. What is ref and what does it do exactly? I have my react code and it does not work. Please if anyone could explain what this ref and this.$el do in react, I'd appreciate it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';

class Chosen extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.el = $(this.el);
        this.$el.chosen();
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.$el.chosen('destroy');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select className="Chosen-select" ref={ el => this.el = el }>
                    { this.props.children }
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Chosen;
```

and also,

```
import React from 'react';
import Chosen from './Chosen';

function Restaurants(props) {

    return (
        <Chosen className="Chosen-select" onChange={ value => console.log(value) }>
            {   
                [{name: 'h'}, {name: 'j'}, {name: 'k'}].forEach( r => {
                    <option>{ r.name }</option>
                })
            }
        </Chosen>
    );
}

export default Restaurants;
```